# Как настроить субдомены Ubuntu?

Tags: хосты, apache2, dns, ubuntu

Есть сервер с убунтой 12.04 ВПСка
Стоит `apache2`, `php5` и т.д., всё как надо.
Есть домен, к ней прикрученый.

При заходе на домен, всё нормально работает - обрабатываются `html`, `php` файлы и т.д., в подпапки тоже заходит (кому нужна такая инфа).

Домен "прописан" в виртуальных хостах `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/mydomain.net` (соответственно и в `sites-available` он тоже есть).
Файлы лежат в папке `/var/www/sites/mydomain.net/httpd`
Всё работает отлично, сайт функционирует нормально, НО... когда я пытаюсь создать поддомен, например добавляя в файл `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/mydomain.net` (или в `httpd.conf`) строчки типа

```
NameVirtualHost *:80<VirtualHost *:80>ServerName sub.mydomain.netDocumentRoot /var/www/sites/sub.mydomain.ru/httpd</VirtualHost>
```

И перегружаю апач, то он мне пишет, что

```
[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

И конечно же ничего не работает. Можно конечно в `ports.conf` закомментировать строку `NameVirtualHost *:80` и ошибки писаться никакой не будет, но и работать тоже ничего не будет.

Далее - если я копирую файл `/etc/apache/sites-available/mydomain.net`, только переназываю его как `sub.mydomain.net` (т.е. в `sites-available` три файла - `default, mydomain.net, sub.mydomain.net`), меняю в нем все пути до папки `sub.mydomain.net/httpd`, "активирую" сайт командой `a2ensite sub.mydomain.net` и перезапускаю апач, то он перезапускается отлично, без варнингов, но и без субдомена...

Вот что мне делать? Всё уже обшарил, все форумы, все темы, блин. Изредка правда что-то говорят про `DNS`-сервер, типа нет каких-то записей, я в этом уже намного прям так меньше понимаю, поэтому я не зна, как проверить, есть ли у меня какие-то записи, чтобы домен третьего уровня заработал или нету. Если что, на сервере `DNS`-сервер не установлен. Но из-за этого ли глюки?

Comment: ну что, разобрался?

Comment: Не, что-то никак не дались поддомены мне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй комментить

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

не в `ports.conf`, а в `/etc/apache/sites-enabled/mydomain.net`

Comment: Пробовал, эффекта ноль.

Comment: А какая ошибка, если     NameVirtualHost *:80уникален и в ports.conf, а в /etc/apache/sites-enabled/mydomain.net     <VirtualHost *:80>ServerName sub.mydomain.net

Comment: В этом случае нет ошибок, но и всё равно не открывает субдомен:)

Comment: а что открывает?

Comment: ничего - ошибка просто, как если несуществующий домен ввести

Comment: так дело значит в отсутствии записи в hosts или dns

Answer (score 1):

А если так  `NameVirtualHost *:*` ?

Comment: Тоже has no virtual host *:0

Answer (score 1):

И не забудь прописать субдомены в /etc/hosts.